# Using cx_freeze to combine 3 .py files into a standalone application?

Tags: python, pyqt, cx-freeze

I am building a PyQt GUI, and it has 3 files: one for the pictures, another that is the actual GUI, and another that actually starts the application.

I have tried py2exe, but since it is all written in Python 3.2 it didn't work. I am not at all familiar with cx_freeze and this project is already a week overdue, so if anyone can help me build this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Might I advise that you use [PyInstaller?](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) I have found it way better than py2exe and cx_freeze when building exe packages. It even handles egg files.

Comment: Could you go in depth on how I would use it? Thanks!

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/tags/1.5.1/doc/Manual.html?format=raw). It is quite simple to use, it comes down to running two commands, Makespec.py and Build.py.